# videoFileReader errors with Matlab+Ubuntu

Tags: matlab, gstreamer, video-processing, matlab-cvst

I'm using Matlab R2013a, Ubuntu 64 12.04

I am trying to read a video file like this:

`ipVidObj = vision.VideoFileReader(fullFileName);`

where fullFileName is a path+filename to a .mp4 file

NOTE: On Windows, the above line works fine.

But on Ubuntu, the following happens:
The above line works sometimes and fails most of the times. 
The first 2 lines of error thats given on the matlab console is this:

```
Error using coder.internal.errorIf (line 9)
Unable to read video from the file. Use dsp.AudioFileReader to read audio content.
```

(Its a long error. Let me know if you want me to paste the whole thing)

I searched around and it looks like this occurs because I might not have gstreamer. But, I do... I have gstreamer1.0 installed. If I install gstreamer0.10, then the same line failes ALWAYS and crashes matlab with the following error:

```
      DtsGetHWFeatures: Create File Failed
      DtsGetHWFeatures: Create File Failed
      Running DIL (3.22.0) Version
      DtsDeviceOpen: Opening HW in mode 0
      DtsDeviceOpen: Create File Failed
      DtsGetHWFeatures: Create File Failed
      Running DIL (3.22.0) Version
      DtsDeviceOpen: Opening HW in mode 0
      DtsDeviceOpen: Create File Failed
      libva: VA-API version 0.32.0
      Xlib:  extension "XFree86-DRI" missing on display ":0".
      libva: va_getDriverName() returns 0
      libva: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
      libva: va_openDriver() returns -1
      Killed
```

I hope some1 has come across this earlier...

Comment: For some reason .avi files seem to work fine with that line of code. I'm going to convert all files to .avi.

Comment: This may be a codec issue, but I assume that you need both the video and audio from the file if you're using `vision.VideoFileReader`. If not, have you tried just using the newer [`VideoReader`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreaderclass.html)? Does the file open with that?

Comment: I only need to do video processing. The audio is useless for me. Do you know if its possible to pass a VideoReader object to the methods in vision class? e.g. vision.OpticalFlow - I think its easier to pass a VideoFileReader object to these functions. I might be wrong.

Comment: I don't have any experience with the Vision toolbox. It looks like `VideoReader` has the same basic capabilities, but you'll have to use it differently as the methods aren't the same (`read` instead of `step` for example). Another option, might just be to use a combination of `VideoReader` and `VideoWriter` (or other software) to save a version of the movie (or selected frames) with the audio stripped and then go back and try `vision.VideoFileReader` again.

Comment: @Kishore - have you succeeded in getting Matlab to work with gstreamer 1.0?